# msbuild ITaskItem output

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, itaskitem

I'm trying to use `MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7AppPool` task with GetInfo task action.
This task's output parameter is SiteInfo property, which its type is ITaskItem. This is a propery, not a collection.

How can I access the SiteInfo metadata? I can access with $, but then all I can get is the web site name. I tried to use %(SiteInfo.) with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the output parameter is an ITaskItem and you want to access the metadata then you need to assign it to an ItemGroup instead of a Property.

```
 <Target Name="Test">

    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7AppPool
      TaskAction="GetInfo"
      Name="DefaultAppPool">

      <Output TaskParameter="AppPoolInfo" ItemName="PoolInfo"  />
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7AppPool>

    <Message Text="AppPool info = [@(PoolInfo)]" />
    <Message Text="AppPool MaxProcesses = [%(PoolInfo.MaxProcesses)]" />

    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7WebSite
      TaskAction="GetInfo"
      Name="Default Web Site">

      <Output TaskParameter="SiteId" PropertyName="WebId"  />
      <Output TaskParameter="SiteInfo" ItemName="WebInfo"  />
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7WebSite>

    <Message Text="WebSite id = [$(WebId)]" />
    <Message Text="WebSite app pool = [%(WebInfo.ApplicationPoolName)]" />

  </Target>
```